# Что такое standard-layout в C++ и зачем он нужен?

Tags: c++, c++11

Читал на английском, но так и не смог разобраться.

Comment: Писал об этом [тут](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/01/29/objects_memory_layout_p1.aspx#pod)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Для всех членов класса одинаковый квалификатор доступа
2. Нет виртуальных ф-ий и виртуальных базовых классов
3. Наследуется (а так же инкапсулирует в себя) только от себе подобных
4. Если есть базовый класс - ( а он тоже может от кого-то наследоваться) - только в *одном* классе есть члены данные
5. Нет членов-данных с типом, коий присутствует в его ирархии

---

*Указатель на такой класс может быть приведён к указателю на его первый член данных и обратно*